# What replaces scipy.misc.bytescale?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

I am running old code using scipy 1.3.1 with the following import:

```
from scipy.misc import bytescale
```

with the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'bytescale'
```

I see that [`bytescale`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.bytescale.html) has been removed since 1.3 ([source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10346)). The thread suggests that the `scikit-image util` module would be a good replacement, but does not offer one.

What is a good alternative to the now deprecated `scipy.misc.bytescale()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no direct equivalent (be able to specify high and low) but you can use things like `skimage.util.img_as_ubyte` for scaling  between 0 and 255, `skimage.util.img_as_uint` for scaling  between 0 and 65535. Check them here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html (The `img_as_*` stuffs)

Answer (score 3):

`skimage.util.img_as_ubyte` is a replacement for `scipy.misc.bytescale`

the [`scipy.misc.bytescale`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.bytescale.html) doc states the following:

> Byte scaling means converting the input image to uint8 dtype and
>   scaling the range to (low, high) (default 0-255). If the input image
>   already has dtype uint8, no scaling is done.

the [`skimage.util.img_as_ubyte`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#img-as-ubyte) doc states the following:

> Convert an image to 8-bit unsigned integer format. Negative input
>   values will be clipped. Positive values are scaled between 0 and 255.